# jQuery form validation not kicking in

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I have written the following code but the form tries to post as if the javascript is not being found?

the code is within the `<head>` of the document:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $('.entrysend').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var error = false;
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var address = $('#address').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        if(name.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            alert("Please complete all fields");
        }
        if(address.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            alert("Please complete all fields");
        }
        if(phone.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            alert("Please complete all fields");
        }
        if(email.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            alert("Please complete all fields");
        }

        if(error == false){
            $.post("compthanks.asp",
                    $(".entry").serialize(),
                    function(result){
                        if($.trim(result) == 'sent'){
                            $('.entrysend').remove();
                            alert("Thanks for entering!");
                        }
                    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form class="entry" action="compthanks.asp" method="post" class="floatClear" name="entryForm">   
    <br class="floatClear" />
    <div class="formwrapper">
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="FullName" />
    </div>

    <div class="formwrapper">
        <textarea name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="formwrapper">
        <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="ContactNumber" />
    </div>

    <div class="formwrapper">
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>

    <div class="formwrapper floatClear">  
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Entry" class="entrysend" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Can anyone point out the reason why the form still submits as opposed to the javascript kicking in?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML too?

Comment: HTML code can help us to find out the problem your code looks perfect here

Comment: Do you have any other jQuery in your HTML page and have you tried what @matpol suggested

Comment: Is your JS included before or after the form element?

Comment: I do...im using backstretch for the background image, @matpol suggestion made no difference. Steve it is in the head of the document as stated

Comment: AHA... If it is the head, then it won't work... I will add my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JS is in the `<head>` of your page, then this won't work.  When you add

```
$('.entrysend').click(function(e){...});
```

there is no element with a class of `entrysend` on the page yet.

To fix that, you have two options:

- Move your JS to the bottom of the page, after the `<form>` element.
- Wrap your JS in a `ready` handler:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.entrysend').click(function(e){...});
});
```

This way, jQuery will wait until all HTML has been added to the DOM before trying to attach the click handler to the `entrysend` element.

UPDATE:

I just added your code to a jsFiddle and noticed that you have JS errors in the code you posted.  It might just be a copy/paste error, but it might be the cause of you issue:

You never close half of you functions.  You end with two curly braces, which only close you last `function` block.  You need to add `)}})` to the and of your JS

- A `)` to close the `$.post`
- A `}` to close the `if(error == false)`
- A `}` to close the anonymous function in the `click` handler
- A `)` to close the click handler

New JS:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.entrysend').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var error = false;
            var name = $('#name').val();
            var address = $('#address').val();
            var phone = $('#phone').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();

            if(name.length == 0){
                var error = true;
                alert("Please complete all fields");
            }
            if(address.length == 0){
                var error = true;
                alert("Please complete all fields");
            }
            if(phone.length == 0){
                var error = true;
                alert("Please complete all fields");
            }
            if(email.length == 0){
                var error = true;
                alert("Please complete all fields");
            }

            if(error == false){
                $.post("compthanks.asp", $(".entry").serialize(),function(result){
                    if($.trim(result) == 'sent'){
                        $('.entrysend').remove();
                        alert("Thanks for entering!");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: funnily enough it was at the bottom of the page but i then moved it to the head to see if it makes a difference....unfortunately your solution makes no change, still goes straight to posting.

Comment: Which of my 2 suggestions did you try?

Comment: OK, just out of curiosity, what does your error console say?  Are there any JS errors?

Comment: never thought of that... "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: excellent thanks! Is there an easy way to check for missed closing brackets etc?

Comment: @John jsfiddle paste your code there use js hint,jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

run the validation onsubmit (on the form) not onclick (on a button) - return false if the validation fails

Comment: remove the preventdefault - you want the form to submit and for the validation to decide whether the submission goes through or not.

Answer (score 0):

//Your script

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $('.entrysend').click(function(e){

        var error = false;
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var address = $('#address').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        if(name.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    alert("Please complete all fields");
                    return false;
                }
        if(address.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    alert("Please complete all fields");
                    return false;
                }
        if(phone.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    alert("Please complete all fields");
                    return false;
                }
        if(email.length == 0){
                    var error = true;
                    alert("Please complete all fields");
                }

        if(error == false){
                    $.post("compthanks.asp", $(".entry").serialize(),function(result){
                    if($.trim(result) == 'sent'){
                       $('.entrysend').remove();
                       alert("Thanks for entering!");
                    }
                }
        </script>
```

//Your form

```
<form class="entry" action="compthanks.asp" method="post" class="floatClear" name="entryForm">   
        <br class="floatClear" />
        <div class="formwrapper">
          <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="FullName" />
        </div>

        <div class="formwrapper">
          <textarea name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="formwrapper">
          <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="ContactNumber" />
        </div>

        <div class="formwrapper">
          <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>

        <div class="formwrapper floatClear">  
          <input name="submit" type="button" value="Send Entry" class="entrysend" />
        </div>
        </form>
```

I have changed your code and provided `return false;` statement if any error occurs so that the form will not gets submitted.

Comment: He doesn't need any `return false` statements, he already is using a `preventDefault` at the beginning. So nothing ever needs to return, because he does an AJAX form submit when there are no errors.  The issue is with syntax errors due to unclosed brackets (which you still haven't closed in your code).